# pySpark COGROUP operation on DF based on keys

Tags: pyspark

I want to perform `coGroup` operation on two relations `A` and `B` with keys `A_key` and `B_key` respectively.

I tried doing this by performing the `groupBy` operation on individual relations and then joining them, but as I found out you cannot perform a join operation on grouped data in case of `PySpark` DF.

Answer (score 1):

From pyspark api documentation, http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.html

```
cogroup(other, numPartitions=None)
For each key k in self or other, return a resulting RDD that contains a tuple with the list of values for that key in self as well as other.
>>> x = sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("b", 4)])
>>> y = sc.parallelize([("a", 2)])
>>> [(x, tuple(map(list, y))) for x, y in sorted(list(x.cogroup(y).collect()))]
[('a', ([1], [2])), ('b', ([4], []))]
```

Comment: I have relations with more than 20 fields and the key is not the first field of the relation. so for applying the `cogroup` function i need to make the key as the first column. How to do that if i dont know the schema but just know the key name

Comment: If you know all other field names, you could do, DF.select('key column',other columns...)